# using apache and node at the same time on cloud9

Tags: php, node.js, apache, cloud9-ide

when i'm using different workspaces for apache and for node - they both work fine.
but, if I want to use node on a "php workspace", I just can't, because the apache is always up and using the port 8080, as well as the node wants to on its env.PORT.

why can't I just close the apache on a php workspace?
can you give me some creative way to make it work?

thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stop Apache in the PHP workspace to use node instead, just run:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Port will be free.

Comment: thanks!! thanks work :)
it did some problem with the c9 runner (the IDE stopped knowing what to do when I ask to run a JS file), but after a minute or two it made me happy! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't have both services listening in one port. There's a couple of things you can do depending on the effort you want to put on it and the sophistication you need for your solution:

1) Keeping "both" on port `8080`: You can emulate that by having Apache listening on 8080, and node in another port say 8888, then make a VirtualHost that points to your IP (127.0.0.1 works too) using **[name based vhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)**, you can have a.mybox:8080 point to your regular workspace, then b.mybox:8080 point to your node workspace. You do this by using Apache's **[ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)** to your `localhost:8888` where node is listening.

2) You can do the same as above, but instead of `NamedVhosts` you can just make a path say /node/ that spits back your `node:8888`, again using `ProxyPass`.

3) Finally, the easiest and fastest solution is just put node in another port, say 8888, and go to that. You can specify the port you're listening as a parameter to the `listen()` call: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback.

You can also do the proxying with Node itself, or with yet another process like nginx or haproxy, or one of many of node's modules like [this one](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). In the end its just easier to keep it in a different port, doing all the other configs might not be worth the hassle.

Finally if you go thru the proxy way with different vhosts, just remember you can define your hosts' names in `/etc/hosts` if you don't have a full domain. Again, easier.

Hope it helps.

Comment: 3. won't work, because Cloud9 gives you 1 port that's accessible to the outside world.

Comment: as Jan said, you ignored the fact that I asked about CLOUD9. this answer is not relevant to the question at all.

Comment: I had the idea that each Cloud9 instance ran in its own Unbuntu image. You can listen to the public port in one but shouldn't keep you for binding to 127.0.0.1:port which should be accessible to the proxy locally.